# How i can color sort cells in excel 2003?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, colors

I want input in six cells(Stores in real life) at every row background colors sort form higher as green color to lower as red color.

In excel 2010 is like the photo but in 2003 version is not working... How i can do this in excel 2003 ?
Photo http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/4909/srv20130328113621.png

In excel 2010 i use this code and work perfect

```
If Application.Version >= "12.0" Then
    For counter = 3 To 103
        Range("I" & counter & ",K" & counter & ",M" & counter & ",O" & counter & ",Q" & counter & ",S" & counter).Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 7039480
    End If
    End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 8711167
    End If
    End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 8109667
    End If
    End With
    Next counter
Else
End If
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you get an error? What happens if you remove the version check?

Comment: AddColorScale doesn't exist in excel 2003 i'm afraid.

Comment: Yes this is the problem...

Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3

Run-time error '438' 
Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok !! With this code working perfect !

In 1st sub xromata(colors in Greek) i have some set for deferents worksheets. 
After this call the sortarisma with reference the first column the different to the second column and the number of rows !!

```
Sub Xromata(a As Integer)
    If a = 1 Then
        Call Sortarisma(11, 3, 103)
        ElseIf a = 2 Then
        Call Sortarisma(12, 3, 111)
        ElseIf a = 3 Then
        Call Sortarisma(9, 2, 103)
        ElseIf a = 4 Then
        Call Sortarisma(10, 2, 111)
        ElseIf a = 5 Then
        Call Sortarisma(11, 4, 103)
        Call Sortarisma(12, 4, 103)
        ElseIf a = 6 Then
        Call Sortarisma(12, 4, 111)
        Call Sortarisma(13, 4, 111)
    Else
End If

End Sub
Sub Sortarisma(arxi As Integer, per As Integer, numofrows As Integer)

Dim Arr(1 To 6) As Single
Dim i As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ff As Integer
Dim ll As Integer
Dim temp As Single
ff = 1
ll = 6

For i = 3 To numofrows
    temp = 0
    Arr(1) = Cells(i, arxi)
    Arr(2) = Cells(i, arxi + per)
    Arr(3) = Cells(i, arxi + (per * 2))
    Arr(4) = Cells(i, arxi + (per * 3))
    Arr(5) = Cells(i, arxi + (per * 4))
    Arr(6) = Cells(i, arxi + (per * 5))

    For k = ff To ll - 1
        For j = k + 1 To ll
            If Arr(k) > Arr(j) Then
            temp = Arr(j)
            Arr(j) = Arr(k)
            Arr(k) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next k
    ''''''''''''''''''''
    For l = arxi To arxi + (per * 5) Step per
        If Cells(i, l) = Arr(1) And Cells(i, l) >= 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 6)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(2) And Cells(i, l) >= 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 5)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(3) And Cells(i, l) >= 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 4)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(4) And Cells(i, l) >= 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 3)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(5) And Cells(i, l) >= 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 2)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(6) And Cells(i, l) >= 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 1)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(1) And Cells(i, l) < 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 6)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(2) And Cells(i, l) < 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 5)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(3) And Cells(i, l) < 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 4)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(4) And Cells(i, l) < 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 3)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(5) And Cells(i, l) < 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 2)
        ElseIf Cells(i, l) = Arr(6) And Cells(i, l) < 0 Then
            Call xromatismos_keliou(i, l, 1)
        End If
    Next l
    Next i
Call addindex(numofrows + 2)
Application.Goto Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True
End Sub
Sub xromatismos_keliou(row As Integer, col As Integer, bathmos As Integer)

If bathmos = 1 Then
    Cells(row, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    ElseIf bathmos = 2 Then
    Cells(row, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
    ElseIf bathmos = 3 Then
    Cells(row, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    ElseIf bathmos = 4 Then
    Cells(row, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    ElseIf bathmos = 5 Then
    Cells(row, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    ElseIf bathmos = 6 Then
    Cells(row, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    Cells(row, col).Select
    With Selection.Font
    .Bold = True
    End With

    Else
End If

End Sub
Sub addindex(thesi As Integer)

Cells(thesi, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
Cells(thesi, 1).Value = "1"
Cells(thesi, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
Cells(thesi, 2).Value = "2"
Cells(thesi, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
Cells(thesi, 3).Value = "3"
Cells(thesi, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
Cells(thesi, 4).Value = "4"
Cells(thesi, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Cells(thesi, 5).Value = "5"
Cells(thesi, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
Cells(thesi, 6).Value = "6"

End Sub
```